# node array.find keeps giving -1

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a MEAN js application in which whenever I use `find` on an array, the callback function is not executed, and `find` straightaway returns `-1`.

When I execute it in an individual file of the project, it work properly, but when I `require` that file in my application, it goes back to `-1`

I'm trying this basic example from firefox site:

```
var inventory = [
    {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
    {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
    {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) {
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries));
```

What might be the reason for this? It used to work properly, now suddenly, `-1` everywhere!

Comment: Maybe some library you use modifies `Array.prototype.find`?

Comment: It works for me, in an individual file, and through `require`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-opcua` was the culprit. Once I do `require("node-opcua")`, the native code of the find function is getting replaced by the following:

```
function (value, equals) {
    equals = equals || this.contentEquals || Object.equals;
    for (var index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
        if (index in this && equals(value, this[index])) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You should file a bug report with that package. Modifying native objects is not good.